# How does the bloom filter works in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I am exploring the cassandra and it seems very interesting, Could someone give me a overview of how bloom filter works?

What is the purpose of it in Cassandra?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bloom Filter (In General) - It is an index based data structure, which gives **definitely not** for objects not available in it, **Sometimes May be available** for objects available in it.

It is used for faster search in Cassandra, It will run in In-Memory, Available in SS Table. (NOTE : This bloom filter will also be available in disk which will be used while restarting)

Check this link for more understanding.

http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlAboutReads.html

Comment: Thanks this link clarifies the use of bloom filter in cassandra which I already have an idea. Is there a link to check for the functional algorithms?

Comment: I think you are expecting algorithm implementation : check this : I learned from this : http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bloom-filters-introduction-and-python-implementation/

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter - a simple standalone bloom filter (apart from those available in cassandra source) is found on github: https://github.com/MagnusS/Java-BloomFilter